# Installing Android SDK Platform tools 23 rc3 automatically uninstalling Android SDK Platform tools 22

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have recently  switched to `Android Studio` from `Eclipse`. I have seen that when I am installing `Android SDK Platform tools 23 rc3` its automatically uninstalling `Android SDK Platform tools 22` ,

And i have seen that when i start `SDK Manager` from `Eclipse` its showing all the version of `Android Api`, where as when i start `SDK Manager` from `Android Studio` it doesn't show me `Android Api Version - 2.0, 3.X, 4.0`.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: please give the reason for down voting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one `Platform Tools` at once so if you install `Android SDK Platform tools 23 rc3` it will replace your `Android SDK Platform tools 22`. If you want to have multiple `Platform Tools` you have to use to multiple separate SDK folders.

If you want to see all the old `Android API` versions in Android Studio SDK Manager you can tick the `Obsolete` checkbox inside the SDK Manager and they will appear.

Comment: Yes i knew that checking obsolete will work, But i was thinking if these `Apis` are obsolete for `Android Studio` then it should be same for `Eclipse`. There you don't have to check obsolete to get those `Api`.

Comment: Eclipse is no no longer officially maintained so it might be a bit outdated compared to Android Studio and won't get any more updates. I think their decision for which are obsolete or not is based on https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html. @BBdev

Comment: Hmm may be, and thanks for the link and clarification.

Comment: No problem! If you feel this is the correct answer please mark it as such @BBdev

Answer (score 0):

> By default, the Android SDK uses the most recent downloaded version of
>   the Build Tools.

Source: [SDK Build Tools Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html)
But in Eclipse, you can choose a specific version by using the `sdk.buildtools` property in the `project.properties` file.

So, If you need a specific version of `Platform Tools`, you need use the same version for `Build tools`(because `Platform Tools` is part of `Build Tools`)
As you can see at screen shot: [image]

**23** version of `Build tools` not uninstalling older build tools.
You just need to point out in `project.properties` particular version like this:

```
sdk.buildtools=21.1.2
```

Or if you are using a gradle, add it to `android` section:

```
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```